# State transitions in mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mobile, state, transition

I was wondering if you can actually apply state transitions to a custom component in Flex mobile projects.

I'd like to have some kind of `Flipview` transition like the one available for `Views` but for a custom component. Is that at all possible?

Currently I simply switch states using `currentState = "stateName"`. Naturally that doesn't really look rich.
If the application performance allows it, a nice transition would be great.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to apply state transitions to custom components in Flex Mobile projects.  What have you tried to do, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Hi @César, I tried adding a <s:transitions> block in my Declarations tag which then includes specific <s:Transition> blocks. The transitions block appears to be the problem as I get an error indicating on that transitions tag. I suppose this is because my component doesn't extend Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

state transitions in mobile projects should be the same as the desktop ones.  I believe the only difference is that the mobile versions actually have orientation states (if you decide to name them - similar to how item renderers work).

Comment: Figured it out quite some time ago, but thanks anyway. Might help others as well.